# Waypoint Jquery Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

Simply trying to change the background color on scroll with waypoint.js and animate.css.
Why is it not working?

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  console.log( "ready!" );
  $('#one').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == "up") {
      $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "#131314" }, 600);
    } else if (direction == "down") {
      $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "#252525" }, 600);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: did you check if waypoints library is being correctly loaded?

Comment: I think so. The console.log( "ready!" ); worked

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs for animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> ...most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

Are you including a plugin that would allow you to animate color properties, like the jQuery Color plugin or jQuery UI? If not, you will need to do so. Waypoints may have nothing to do with this problem.